# Excel chart a line per category

Tags: excel, excel-charts

unfortunately I can not manage to acomplisch a simple task in excel. I want to have a separate line in the chart for each category (car model), where x-axis is date and y-axis is price. I have the following table:

```
Modell  Preis   Inserat online seit
318i     6,999 €    30.04.2021
325i     9,999 €    01.05.2021
320i     9,999 €    30.04.2021
318i     9,990 €    28.04.2021
318i     7,500 €    21.04.2021
318i     7,900 €    15.04.2021
```

I've tried to also to use pivot table, it groups the data for each car model, however I still can not find out how to plot it the way I want it.

Thanks,
Slava

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, pivot chart is the best choice for your problem.
But, before you create a line chart, make sure you have enough data for all categories otherwise you will not see lines for all categories. In your sample data, you do not have enough data for all car models.

I have used following sample:

[image]

After that, I inserted a pivot chart.
While creating pivot chart, I choose "Date" for Axis (Catagories) and "Model" for Legend (Series) and "Price" for Values. Like this:

[image]

Then I simply change the chart type to "Line Chart" by right clicking on the default chart provided by excel.
And I got the result like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it is working for me. I was not correctly using PivotChart fields before.

Comment: My pleasure to know... it's working. If my answer was helpful or solved your problem then could you please accept my answer? That will help other person with same question to find answer quickly.